# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' in system.drawing.image

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

i store my website image in form of byte array , but when i try to save them as jpeg file ,some of this file throw exception.here is my code for get image:

```
IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(ApplicationUser).GetProperties()
                               .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(Byte[])).ToList();

var imaBytes = property.GetValue(user, null) as Byte[];
if (imaBytes == null || imaBytes.Length == 0) continue;

Image userImage = ImageHelper.byteArrayToImage(imaBytes);   
userImage.Save(pathname + $@"\{DirName}\" + property.Name + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

and this is my `ImageHelper.byteArrayToImage` :

```
public static Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
        using (var image = Image.FromStream(ms,false,true))
        {
            byteArrayIn = new byte[0];
            return new Bitmap(image); 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       Logger.log(e);
    }
}
```

edit:
i wrap MemoryStream and Image code with using statment and  change my code and add ImageToDisk method :

```
public static void ImageToDisk(byte[] byteArrayIn, string pathToSave)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            {
                using (var image = Image.FromStream(ms, false, true))
                {
                    image.Save(pathToSave, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    image.Dispose();

                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.log(e);
            throw;
        }

    }
```

and main code is this:

```
 foreach (var property in properties)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var imaBytes = property.GetValue(user, null) as Byte[];
                            if (imaBytes == null || imaBytes.Length == 0)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            ImageHelper.ImageToDisk(imaBytes, pathname + $@"\{DirName}\" + property.Name + ".jpg");

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            LogException(ex);
                        }
                    }
```

but now am getting `system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception`
**EDIT 2:**
i am completely dizzy!!! its seems some user upload images from IE and IE change MIME type to image/PJPEG
[image]
error occurred is some file with this MIME type but also some other `image/PJPEG` files save correctly without any exception
[image]
how can i resolve this error??

Comment: From earlier experience, the error checking in the image loading code is somewhat flawed so it may simply be that the image file is corrupt, or using extensions or compression methods that .NET doesn't support. For instance, if you have an image that says it is HUUGE then .NET will actually try to load the image and allocate the memory, instead of kicking back an exception.

Comment: One thing about your code though, why are you allocating *two* images, why not simply `return Image.FromStream(...);` instead of doing that in a using block and constructing a bitmap around it?

Comment: What format is the image in the byte array in?

Comment: thank you for comment ,images are JPEG but some image are saved correctly!

Comment: @MoshheghFaghdan OOM are almost always caused because `Dispose()` wasn't called on objects that need disposing, lots of temporary objects (like those created by string operations) or frequent resizing of large arrays. All these create temporary objects that will be garbage collected at some point. In the mean time though they create a *lot* of memory fragmentation. The runtime may not be able to find a large enough block to allocate the new `byte` array or that new List

Comment: Please never write `catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); throw; }`. That's just a waste of your time and effort. Let the environment deal with these errors for you.

Comment: @MoshheghFaghdan make sure you dispose all GDI objects. Pass a `capacity` parameter to any List constructor to avoid reallocations. *Reuse* `byte[]` buffers instead of allocating new ones. You can use BufferManager or ArrayPool to reuse `byte[]` buffers from a pool of ready-made buffers instead of creating new ones.

Comment: @Enigmativity thank you for advise ,this is just test code , not final!

Comment: @MoshheghFaghdan - You shouldn't put it in test code either. Why do you feel that this is useful in test code?

Comment: @Enigmativity i mean this is not final production code,i just get this code from another Q/A in SO :)))))))))

Comment: Are you disposing userImage

Comment: @Gauravsa nope! i dont know how to dispose it,how can i do it by calling dispose method??

Answer (score 3):

> some of this file throw exception

I'm almost sure the problem is with disposing your images. Make sure all resources are released:

```
using (Image userImage = ImageHelper.byteArrayToImage(imaBytes))
{
  //do whatever you need
  userImage.Save(pathname + $@"\{DirName}\" + property.Name + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Bitmaps consume a lot of memory. Under the hood `Image` uses `GdipLoadImageFromStream` method. To release resources, it should be paired with `GdipDisposeImage`. That's what happens inside `Image.Dispose()` method.

Comment: Matter of fact the GDI code does not distinguish and throws OOM exceptions even for things like "not enough handles", so not disposing could indeed be a culprit here.

Comment: i don't test code yet , but its seem to work correctly ,but what real image was png format?? is error cause for incorrect image format??

Comment: No, image format is not important. Just make sure `userImage` is disposed correctly.

Comment: @PawełDyl i try it but currently it exception thrown 'system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception' in system.drawing.dll